# Powershell Search for AD Users

Tags: powershell, active-directory, windowsdomainaccount

I am learning Powershell and use it frequently for adding users to AD Groups. I would like to know if it is possible to search for AD Usernames using the persons common name (i.e. John Doe = JDoe). It is very time consuming and defeats the purpose of using Powershell if I have to use AD Users and Computers to look up their UID every time.

UPDATE: I tried the **Get-ADUser -filter { cn -eq 'John Doe' }** and **Get-ADUser -filter { Name -eq 'John Doe' }** command and I did not receive any output from the console, it immediately went to the next line.

I also have RSAT installed, just to clarify. I have looked at the technet article on MS' page [Get-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/hh852208(v=wps.630).aspx) to try and figure it out before I posted the OP.

Just to clarify I am looking to search by the Common Name to find that user's Login Name. i.e. Searching 'John Doe' to find 'jdoe' the User Logon Name.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You may want to have a look at the [tour] and [help], to learn how questions should be asked on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to install RSAT. See [here](https://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-install-the-powershell-active-directory-module/) for instructions for various Windows versions.

Then use [Get-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617241.aspx):

```
Get-ADUser -filter { cn -eq "Common Name" }
```

Comment: This doesn't give me any output unfortunately. Ran in Administrator mode.

Comment: What you put in quotes must match exactly to the "cn" attribute of the user. Also, is the user account that you are looking for on the same domain that you are logged into?

Comment: Thank you, so the part in quotes was wrong, because the format we have been using is "Doe, John". Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your specific question is, but you can use the AD cmdlets to search using ambiguous name resolution (ANR):

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(anr=jdoe)'
```

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243299 for more information about ANR.

To search by the `cn` attribute only, just change the LDAP filter:

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter '(cn=John Doe)'
```

Comment: ANR is cool too, although it doesn't search the 'cn' attribute.

Comment: I am looking to search by Common Name to get the User Logon Name